# ignore AIR-specific classes in Web project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

I have a project which is destined for multiple platforms (iOS, Android, Web, Desktop)

The codebase for the vast majority of it works everywhere just fine and I'd like to keep it to one common codebase/folder

However, there is one class that needs AIR-specific classes like File. For the web, it uses a different method to achieve the same requirements

Let's assume the AIR version of the class is AirClass and the Web version is WebClass

The problem I'm facing is- how can I tell Flash Builder to not at all compile the AirClass where I need to use WebClass instead?

Right now, even if I'm not actually using AirClass, the project won't compile (since it is referenced in the code for the cases where it's running on AIR)

Comment: you can change In the preferences, so that the Flash Builder won't mark it as an error but as warning.

Comment: Interesting idea... is that dangerous in any way? :)

Comment: If you won't check the that the device you're running can run it'll crash on the runtime.

Comment: Thanks... having trouble finding it in the preferences though (Flash Builder 4.7)